# Create a Table with highlighted Source Code in Asciidoc

Tags: ascii, asciidoc, ascii-art, asciidoctor

I would like to highlight some of my code in tables. I tried many ways but I could get it fixed.

I would appreciate if someone can help me.

Answer (score 8):

great question!

Most AsciiDoc syntax is not rendered inside a table, only basic syntax like `*bold*`. 
You have to explicitly tell Asciidoctor to render the whole feature set.

There are two ways to do so:

1) prepend the character `a` to the `|` of the cell where you want Asciidoctor to render the full syntax

2) configure a whole column to be rendered as AsciiDoc by stating your wish in front of the table: `[cols="a,a"]` will render a AsciiDoc in both columns of a two column table.

here is a gist to demonstrate this:
https://gist.github.com/rdmueller/b79f4b00890f75644a0186c4adda589a

docs can be found here: https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#cols-format

Examples:

```
|====
|Col1 | Col2
| even complex formattings like source code highlighting works this way
a|
[source, groovy]
----
5.times {
    println it
}
----
|====
```

```
[cols="a,a"]
|====
|Col1 | Col2
| even complex formattings like source code highlighting works this way
|
[source, groovy]
----
5.times {
    println it
}
----
|====
```

See the gist for a rendering of these examples

Comment: Could you give me maybe an example?

Comment: do these examples fit?